# Program "returns" and exits using 2d char array pointers in loop?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm really baffled by my program's behavior. I'm trying to read from a file and represent the entire file as a 2d char array, but for some reason it seems to just "return" or exit whenever I'm trying to assign a char to an element in that array... Any ideas what I'm missing here?

(Oh and I want it to cut off after the first 10 characters)

Thanks kindly.
(Edited: added headers and main)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fpin;

    fpin = fopen("tester.txt", "r");

    char (*strings)[20][10];      //Array of strings contains entire file
    bool continueReading = true; //boolean for end of file: end of file = 0

/* ===THIS WORKS===
    (*strings)[0][0] = 'f';
    printf("\nPutting character: %c", (*strings)[0][0]);
    return 0;
*/
    int whileLoops = 0;
    while (continueReading)
    {
        //grab first char
        char ch = fgetc(fpin);

        //if no charaters exist break
        if (ch == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        {
            printf("\nPutting character: %c", ch);
            printf(" in Strings - %d", whileLoops);
            printf(" - 0");
            (*strings)[whileLoops][0] = ch;
/* === PROGRAM TERMINATES HERE, NO ERRORS ??? === */
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {

            //concat char by passing to array
            ch = fgetc(fpin); //repeat with next char from infile

            if (ch == '\n') // newline char
            {
                break; //break here go back into while loop
            }
            else if (ch == EOF)
            {
                continueReading = false;
                break;
            }

            if (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
            {
                printf("\nPutting character: %c", ch);
                printf(" in Strings - %d", whileLoops);
                printf(" - %d", i);
                (*strings)[whileLoops][i] = ch;
            }

            if (i+1 >= 10)
            {
                while (1)
                {
                    ch = fgetc(fpin); //repeat with next char from infile
                    if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)   // newline char
                    {
                        break; //break here go back into while loop
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        whileLoops++;
    }

    fclose(fpin);
    return 0;
}
```

Input File:

```
Tony Buffet
Kailey Heson
Art Johnson
John Pernanski
```

Output:

```
Putting character: T in Strings - 0 - 0
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of `fpin`?

Comment: Your program has insufficient protection against overrunning the bounds of array `strings`.  It is plausible that the specific failure you observe is related to such an overrun, but we would need to see the input to be sure.  Also, what the program does with lines containing exactly 10 non-newline characters is probably not what you expect, and what it does with longer lines might not be what you expect.

Comment: Note that `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  You can run into problems detecting EOF if you use `char`.

Comment: Apart from the char -> int bug, `if (ch != '\n' || ch != EOF)` also doesn't seem to make any sense. De Morgan's laws... you probably meant `&&`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for catching the or. Still not working but that helped Lundin.

Comment: The input is just a file containing 4 lines of names. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is how you define and access the array.
This is hinted at by the compiler if you include the `-Wall` flag:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main -Wall
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:35:39: warning: 'strings' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   35 |             (*strings)[whileLoops][0] = ch;
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

[`char (*strings)[20][10]`](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+%28*strings%29%5B20%5D%5B10%5D) defines a **pointer** to a 2D array, whereas what you want is *just* the array: `char strings[20][10]`.
Now you can access the array using `strings[whileLoops][0] = ch` and the code works.

Comment: That `-Wall` flag is really useful.